# SOQL statement inside a getter/setter - what benefits?

Tags: apex, soql, getter

I've seen some SOQL done in a getter as such:

```
    public static Map<String, sObjectHere> methodName {
        get {
                someMapHere = new Map<String, sObjectHere>();
                List<sObjectHere> sobjectList = [SELECT <Fields here> FROM sObjectHere];

                for (sObjectHere i : sobjectList) {
                    someMapHere.put(key, value);
                }                

            return someMapHere;
        }

        private set;
    }
```

What benefits des this serve over a regular method that returns a soql statement and then iterating it and putting it in a map. What does `get` do in this context?

Answer (score 4):

In this example there **is no difference** than having a `getMap()` method that always executes the same code as in the getter. Not to be too nitpicky with terms, but what you have is a [property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) and not a [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm).

Normally, you use a syntax like this to [lazy load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) (see also, [lazy instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)) properties of a class. This has two benefits:

1. you only consume the time needed to get the property if it's actually needed instead of automatically initializing it when the class is first referenced and
2. repeated accesses of the property don't go all the way back to the database to fetch the values, which improves performance and conserves query limits.

These are particularly helpful in an environment like Salesforce where governor limits dictate how much you can get away with in any given transaction.

Lazy loading example:

```java
public static Map<Id, Contact> contactMap {
  get {
    // if contactMap hasn't been initialized yet, initialize it
    if(contactMap == null) {
        contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact LIMIT 100]);
    }
    // subsequent calls don't need to execute the query
    return contactMap;
  }
  private set;
}
```

Comment: I removed the method itself and only posted the content of it, but you’re right. Would it ever make sense to return a regular soql query in a getter as well? And not just as a ‘map’ in the above example

Comment: Sure, if what you want is a `List` instead of a `Map`. It's all about the need. You could have the getter instantiate a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), keep a count of accesses, or run any sort of logic on access.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `private set;` in the example above? I looked at the docs abit and from my understanding, the property should not be writeable. Yet, I could create use the `.put` method on the map to populate it - I assumed private set meant that the variable could only be read and not edited

Comment: The `private` [access modifier](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) means contactMap is able to be set only within the class it's declared in. If it were public instead then other classes would be able to set `MyClass.contactMap = ...`. It's worth reading a bit on access modifiers because they're a concept used in many object-oriented languages. But the gist is: public = other classes and see it, protected = descendent classes can see it, private = only the class itself can see it.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using it the intended way, but I created a gist to illustrate my concern: https://gist.github.com/erikmalmberg/c163e607c75cb3da2d68995511f5aa10

What am I missing here? It looks like I can add key-value pairs to a map, even though it has a `private set` on it

Comment: So what's happening here is a bit nuanced. You are _not_ setting the Map from outside the class (by accessing the setter), but you are getting it with a public `get` (which returns a reference to the Map) and then you are modifying it with its public `put` method.

Comment: So, can you provide an example of how this `private set` would work in action? Preferably with the example provided

Comment: Sure in your example try `ExampleClass.getAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>()`. You will get the following error: `Error: Variable is not visible: ExampleClass.getAccounts`. I will say that your example, as currently written, does not offer any of the benefits of lazy loading because your query will execute _every time_ the property is accessed.

Comment: I removed the `if(map == null)` part for simplicity - I guess that's where the benefits comes in. I still have a hard time understanding private set though. I get what the documentation is trying to say, but I just can't understand any real, practical scenarios for it

Comment: It may be best for you to ask that as its own question. `private set` means the property can only be set from the class its declared in. [See this post on StackOverflow. It's for C# but the use case is the same as in Apex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847832/understanding-private-setters)